# React - Inherit / copy propTypes from another Component

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

I wanna copy / inherit propTypes fron another component, how do i archive it with React?

```
<Header>
 <LibHeader />
</Header>
```

-> `Header` will have all `LibHeader` propTypes without re-declaration and has it own propTypes.

I've tried with this but doesn't work

```
Header.propTypes = {
...LibHeader.propTypes,
search: PropTypes.func,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a general PropType object which you can share

```
HeaderProps = {
  foo: PropTypes.string,
  bar: PropTypes.string,
}

LibHeader.propTypes = HeaderProps;
Header.propTypes = {
  ...HeaderProps,
  search: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: `LibHeader` already has propTypes, and i don't wanna redeclare it, i want to re-use (inherit) it on my wrapped component. What you're doing is to reset LibHeader propTypes before reuse it.